# .git/config file reads "command not found"

Tags: macos, git, configuration-files

I am attempting to learn git and using mac osx 10.8

Upon looking in the .git/config file in the repository I have created, the file reads,

```
/.git/config: line 1: [core]: command not found
/.git/config: line 2: repositoryformatversion: command not found
/.git/config: line 3: filemode: command not found
/.git/config: line 4: bare: command not found
/.git/config: line 5: logallrefupdates: command not found
/.git/config: line 6: ignorecase: command not found
/.git/config: line 7: precomposeunicode: command not found
/.git/config: line 8: [remote: command not found
/.git/config: line 9: url: command not found
/.git/config: line 10: fetch: command not found
logout

[Process completed]
```

when, as my lesson book tells me, it should say,

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
ignorecase = true
precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
url = https://github.com/joesmith2444/my-first-repository.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
```

Does anyone know what might be the cause?  Please let me know if any other specifics are needed.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't accidentally running it as a bash script? Just verifying that is the actual content of the file.

Comment: `.git/config` is a plain ini-style file, you shouldn't try to execute it. `git config` is a command which queries and/or updates this file

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because you are trying to *execute* the config file. Choose one of the following options:-

**View file**

```
cat .git/config
```

**Edit file**

```
nano .git/config
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to try to execute your `.git/config` file...  You probably wanted to do `git clone https://github.com/joesmith2444/my-first-repository.git`?

Also make sure you have Git installed.  Perhaps your shell helpfully spelling-corrected "no executable git binary in your $PATH" to "execute the first thing in your $PATH that looks like git".